# Viewing image file bytes

Tags: python-3.x, binary

Not looking for help accomplishing anything specific. Looking to understand what is happening. Can anyone explain or point to a source to help me understand? Thank you.

I have a JPEG containing 1 pixel with a (0,0,0) RGB value.

Opening in a text editor shows 631 hexadecimal pairs. The 1st pair is 'ff'.

Opening in Python as binary:

```
f = open('Image0.jpg','rb')
g = f.read()
```

The first byte prints as 255, which corresponds to the first hex pair 'ff'.

```
g[0]
255
```

Printing the first byte with 'bytes()' format gives 255 'x00' values. This is what I don't understand: 'x00' is zero but 255 base-ten is '11111111' base-two. What am I seeing when I print this as bytes? I'm missing something fundamental but what is it?

```
bytes(g[0])
b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\...
```

Answer (score 0):

See the [docs for `bytearray`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-bytearray) (`bytes` is just an immutable `bytearray`). I've reproduced the relevant portion below.

> The optional `source` parameter can be used to initialize the array in a few different ways:
>
> - If it is an integer, the array will have that size and will be initialized with null bytes.